# Are async/promises in javascript (in the browser) beneficial where there's no I/O?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

I'm trying to find a good deserializer/denormalizer for json-api (which is proving surprisingly difficult).

I've come across a few examples where the deserialization process (basically just denormalizing the relationships and flattening attributes) is defined as an async function. [Here's one such example](https://github.com/wopian/kitsu/tree/master/packages/kitsu-core#deserialise), but there are many that I've found.

Now, my understanding of node/javascript is that it is predicated on systems being I/O bound, so its design is such that operations should be non-blocking so that other operations can be scheduled during I/O and thus we get concurrent operations.

What I don't understand however is the usage within a deserializer such as this. We have the full payload at the time of deserialization, there's no I/O occurring whatsoever. I can only guess that the author assumes that the relationship lookups could all happen concurrently, however, since javascript is still single threaded, I can't see how this could in any way improve performance.

It seems to me this is just making a deterministic operation non deterministic (since I suppose the schedule could also schedule *other* operations besides the deserialization).

Am I missing something here? Is there truly a benefit to making this asynchronous? I'm not a front-end (or a node) developer so I feel like I'm missing something (since I've seen this pattern used in deserializers a LOT)

This will be run in the browser (not a node backend) if it makes any difference.

Comment: They might be. If there's a huge chunk of work to be done, it might make sense to split it to smaller chunks. The point is, processing still takes N units of time, but there might be some work done in between - serving other requests, or issuing I/O, for example.

Comment: Especially in a browser, all UI would freeze until the data has been processed. And a server would be unable to accept any new connections in the meantime. For large amounts of data, that may be a significant problem.

Comment: Ya ok that makes sense. But if I'm on a page whose primary goal is to display the data it just fetched (can't do much else without it) I'd generally want to optimize the deserialization of that data I'd think no?

Comment: Yes, it's essentially a trade-off (always is). But the overhead is (relatively) small, and the benefit of non-blocking is (usually) high enough to justify it. Even browsers' behavior these days forces you to go that way - or deal with that pesky 'Unresponsive script...' warnings.

Comment: Asyncronicity has religion status in the Javascript world - it is not always appropriate but it's nearly always done that way. There are exceptions eg the very useful https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-sqlite3 and Node supplies synchronous versions of many routines. In the browser you can use WebWorkers to do processing without blocking the main i/o and in Node you can use a child process. Promises/Async will kill performance relative to callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems, the authors of the library that you mentioned as an example do not use async / await correctly:

```
 // see: https://github.com/wopian/kitsu/blob/master/packages/kitsu-core/src/deattribute/index.js

 // v does await nothing, as it receives an array
 //                v unneccessary
 await data.map(async el => deattribute(el))
```

There is no reason to use `async` / `await` at all here, so I doubt that it serves any purpose in the library.

> Are async/promises in javascript (in the browser) beneficial where there's no I/O?

No. Although promises are always resolved asynchronously , they will still end up in the so called microtask queue (in browsers), which will be emptied before the browser does rerender, therefore calling async functions will not help you to unfreeze the UI.

> I can only guess that the author assumes that the relationship lookups could all happen concurrently, however, since javascript is still single threaded, I can't see how this could in any way improve performance.

I agree, this won't increase performance at all.

> It seems to me this is just making a deterministic operation non deterministic (since I suppose the schedule could also schedule other operations besides the deserialization).

No, it could not, as there is no asynchronous IO involved that would free the engine from it's current task. Therefore it will still run in a blocking way.

Comment: That's not true: Promises are resolved in microtasks, which make the current event loop grow and will actually freeze the engine even more than a simple while loop which has many safe guards against itself at least in browsers: https://jsfiddle.net/srx4fb81/

Comment: "*therefore the engine will get unblocked, allowing it to rerender and do other tasks.*" - no, immediately resolved promises run in a microtask, before any other tasks or rendering, and will block the engine until there are no promise handlers left to run. Your `looksSync` does not help to run anything concurrently.

Comment: @bergi then I don't see any reason why the library is using async / await at all

Comment: @kaiido hmm, i thought the browser would somewhen stop working on microtasks, seems I was wrong completely

Comment: @JonasWilms You mean the library that the OP linked? Yes indeed, from judging [this code](https://github.com/wopian/kitsu/blob/master/packages/kitsu-core/src/deattribute/index.js#L29-L36) the author has no idea of `async`/`await`. Maybe they just wanted to put "*Uses the Promise API*" in their "Features" section? All the code within kitsu-core is entirely synchronous, promises would be useful only for the async network stuff in kitsu.

Comment: @bergi I had exactly the same thought :)

Comment: @Kaiido Microtasks don't have to block, have a look at [my example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55362240/3982562).

Comment: @3limin4t0r `Promise.resolve` gets *directly* moved into the microtask queue, if you use a timer that won't happen. However a timer does count as IO, and the library the OP mentioned does not use timers at all.

Comment: @JonasWilms Yep, I noticed that in the source. The question was not about that specific library, but in general form though.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down voted. This seems like a sufficiently accurate explanation of what I was trying to figure out. Thanks!

Comment: @brad apologies for my initial confusion, I thought deceze and raina77ow would've looked at the library ... Well votes on SO are often quite random, I seriously don't care :), I'm just here to help, glad that it helped you

Answer (score -3):

One reason that comes to my mind is to distribute the CPU load. Possibly splitting a heavy duty into smaller tasks.

Let me provide you with an example scenario. Let's say that you have for some reason you have an array containing multiple JSON strings. You could do something like this:

```
array = json_array.map(json => JSON.parse(json));
```

This will block all other JavaScript until the entire execution is finished. If the parser provides an asynchronous interface you allow user events and other JavaScript code to run in-between the parsing of every element.

```
array = await Promise.all(json_array.map(json => deserialise(json)));
```

This essentially splits up every every JSON de-serialisation into its own task.

You might think this wouldn't work if you have one large JSON string instead of an array. However you'll have to keep in mind that JSON de-serialisation is basically a recursive call until it reaches a primary data type. I can only guess that this is also used in the internals to split the whole JSON de-serialisation process up into micro tasks. With the main purpose keeping the application responsive.

> **note:** As [pointed out by Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55358764/are-async-promises-in-javascript-in-the-browser-beneficial-where-theres-no-i/55362240#comment97443830_55359400). The linked library tries to do this, but suffers from immediately resolved promise blocking. So there is no benefit in using the linked library. Which appends the resolved promises before other browser tasks, rendering the UI still useless.

I'll a use tweaked version of the [JSFiddle of Kaiido](https://jsfiddle.net/srx4fb81/) ([comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55358764/are-async-promises-in-javascript-in-the-browser-beneficial-where-theres-no-i/55362240#comment97443749_55359400)) as example:

```js
const timer = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
var toggle;
  
onclick = async function updateBg() {
  // simulate an recurring function that would block
  // 5 seconds when ran synchronously
  const start1 = performance.now();
  async function recurringFunction() {
    const start2 = performance.now();
    console.log('fired');

    // simulate a run duration of a few ms each time called
    while (performance.now() - start2 < 5);

    // make recuring calls for ~5 seconds
    if (performance.now() - start1 < 5000) {
      // pass control back to the JavaScript engine by waiting 0ms
      await timer(0); 
      return recurringFunction();
    }
  }

  // do something before JSON parsing
  document.body.style.background =
    (toggle = !toggle) ? 'LightSalmon' : 'LightCoral';

  // parse the JSON
  await recurringFunction();

  // do something with the result
  document.body.style.background = 'PaleGreen';
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
click the background to toggle its colour
```